# C++ Wininet Custom http headers

Tags: c++, http, header, wininet

I'm using dev c++, Wininet lib to download a file from web. I'm trying to change the referer or user agent. I use this code, it downloads successfully, but I don't know how to change http headers. Thanks.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wininet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace {

    ::HINTERNET netstart ()
    {
        const ::HINTERNET handle =
            ::InternetOpenW(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, 0, 0, 0);
        if ( handle == 0 )
        {
            const ::DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
            std::cerr
                << "InternetOpen(): " << error << "."
                << std::endl;
        }
        return (handle);
    }

    void netclose ( ::HINTERNET object )
    {
        const ::BOOL result = ::InternetCloseHandle(object);
        if ( result == FALSE )
        {
            const ::DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
            std::cerr
                << "InternetClose(): " << error << "."
                << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ::HINTERNET netopen ( ::HINTERNET session, ::LPCWSTR url )
    {
        const ::HINTERNET handle =
            ::InternetOpenUrlW(session, url, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        if ( handle == 0 )
        {
            const ::DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
            std::cerr
                << "InternetOpenUrl(): " << error << "."
                << std::endl;
        }
        return (handle);
    }

    void netfetch ( ::HINTERNET istream, std::ostream& ostream )
    {
        static const ::DWORD SIZE = 1024;
        ::DWORD error = ERROR_SUCCESS;
        ::BYTE data[SIZE];
        ::DWORD size = 0;
        do {
            ::BOOL result = ::InternetReadFile(istream, data, SIZE, &size);
            if ( result == FALSE )
            {
                error = ::GetLastError();
                std::cerr
                    << "InternetReadFile(): " << error << "."
                    << std::endl;
            }
            ostream.write((const char*)data, size);
        }
        while ((error == ERROR_SUCCESS) && (size > 0));
    }

}

int main ( int, char ** )
{
    const ::WCHAR URL[] = L"http://google.com";
    const ::HINTERNET session = ::netstart();
    if ( session != 0 )
    {
        const ::HINTERNET istream = ::netopen(session, URL);
        if ( istream != 0 )
        {
            std::ofstream ostream("googleindex.html", std::ios::binary);
            if ( ostream.is_open() ) {
                ::netfetch(istream, ostream);
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Could not open 'googleindex.html'." << std::endl;
            }
            ::netclose(istream);
        }
        ::netclose(session);
    }
}

#pragma comment ( lib, "Wininet.lib" )
```

Comment: It's mentioned under "HTTP Sessions" in the WinInet documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You pass user agent string as the first parameter to `InternetOpen`

Use `HttpOpenRequest` and `HttpSendRequest` in place of `InternetOpenUrl`. Referer string is the 5th parameter to `HttpOpenRequest`

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of [InternetOpenUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098(v=vs.85).aspx) is *lpszHeaders [in]* (from MSDN):

> A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the headers to be sent to the HTTP server. For more information, see the description of the lpszHeaders parameter in the HttpSendRequest function.

You can set Referer and User agent like that:

```
LPWSTR headers = L"User-Agent: myagent\r\nReferer: my.referer.com\r\n\r\n\r\n";
//and then call
::InternetOpenUrlW(session, url, headers, -1, 0, 0);
```

You must separate every header with \r\n and close the block with \r\n\r\n

Comment: worth noting that both InternetOpenUrl and HttpSendRequest have a headers parameter